# Rails 5.1 Angular templateUrl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, templates

### Question

What do I need to do to get my Angular application to allow me to use the `templateUrl` property of the `Component` decorator?  When you create a new Rails 5.1 application and use the flag `--webpack=angular`, it gives you a proof of concept Angular application, but as soon as I started creating more components, I began to recognize that I don't know how to refer to the correct path that the templates are being served.  I'm not even sure if they are being served, to be honest.

### What I've tried

- Tried many different variations of the path, from just the file name all the way to the root of the application, one folder at a time.
- Googling for someone else running into the same problem.
- include the `CommonModule` in my imports in `app.module.ts`.

### Background

I'm really used to using the Angular CLI and I don't remember ever having an issue using the `templateUrl` property.  What is different about an Angular CLI project to what's given to you in a Rails 5.1 app in terms of configuration affecting templates?  Would I be able to use Angular CLI in a Rails 5.1 app without having to change much of the Rails app itself?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope :(  It was a toy application, so I haven't been working on it lately unfortunately.

Comment: I had the same question and it was answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230353/angular-4-templateurl-file-not-found/44231278?noredirect=1#comment75495475_44231278

Comment: @Doctor06, thank you so much!  I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

Can be done. But this needs a different webpack loader setup and several minor tweaks.

But first: shopping!

```
$ yarn add \
    html-loader \
    awesome-typescript-loader \
    angular2-template-loader \
    @types/node \
    --dev
```

With all required packages installed replace `config/webpack/loaders/angular.js` with this:

```
const {env} = require('../configuration.js');
isProd = env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
module.exports = {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { useCache: !isProd }
        },
        'angular2-template-loader'
    ]
};
```

`angular2-template-loader` scans your Component decorators for the `templateUrl` argument and replaces it with something like `template: require('...')'`. The `require()` call is the reason for installing `@types/node` by the way.
`awesome-typescript-loader` is a bit more optimized than the default `ts-loader` (which will probably work here as well, but I didn't test it).

So far so good. Next we need to tell webpack how to actually load HTML files. Add `config/webpack/loaders/html.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader',
};
```

Nothing obscure here. Moving on.

In your Javascript app add type informations for *.html files to `app/javascript/hello_angular/html.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.html" {
  const content: string
  export default content
}
```

This tells the TypeScript compiler that `require('template.html')` returns a string.

Last but not least you have add .html to the recognized extensions in `config/webpacker.yml`:

```
default: &default
  # ...
  extensions:
    # ...
    - .html
    # ...
```

Now you should be good to go:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-angular',
  templateUrl: './template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular!';
}
```

Don't forget to restart `bin/webpack-dev-server`.

Theoretically you could do the same for `styleUrls`. But this is more tangled with rails/webpacker and you would loose some of it's features.