# Angular 4 templateUrl file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am using Angular 4.1.3 with Rails 5.1

I am trying to implement the app component and if I use template and write my html, everything works, but I want to use templateUrl.

Here is my component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

And this is my file structure

```
├── app
|   ├── app.component.html
|   └── app.component.ts
|   └── app.module.ts
```

I understand that in the @Component you can add moduleId: module.id but I thought this is no longer needed in angular 4.1.3.

If I do add it, it tells me:
`moduleId should be a string in "AppComponent"`

I also thought that if you do not include the moduleId angular just grabs from root directory, but if I do an absolute path, it should work right?

If you guys could help, that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with `moduleId` but with rails/webpacker not supporting `templateUrl` by default. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45170420/616292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you're using the new [webpacker-gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) in your rails project!

There is a description of how to use templateUrl with it here in the documentation: [Use HTML templates with Typescript and Angular](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/227661b546701e107213aa9b6f83451bc89cf7d5/docs/typescript.md#html-templates-with-typescript-and-angular)

Comment: Please comment if you need additional information, I cannot comment on your original question unfortunately :/

Comment: sorry, i just barely got to where i could try this, and now that i tried the steps i get this error. `Promise rejection: Failed to load %3Ch1%3EHello%20%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%3C/h1%3E ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load %3Ch1%3EHello%20%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%3C/h1%3E`

Comment: Its like its not getting transpiled.

Comment: Are you sure you are still using `template` instead of `templateUrl` with the described method?

Comment: Wait... why does that work? I guess the docs do say template, but why since we are using a template file?

Comment: [Html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader) exports the complete template file as a string. Webpack compiles the string into the component template typescript file. You can have a separate template file this way but must specifiy `template` since you're _actually_ compiling the string template into the file.

Comment: Is your question answered this way? Please mark if answered :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep templateUrl you could use angular2-template-loader webpack plugin:

```
# add plugins to project
yarn add angular2-template-loader raw-loader
```

and configure it:

```
# edit config/webpack/loaders/angular.js with
module.exports = {
    test: /.ts$/,
    loaders: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
    exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
}

# create a new loader for htmls config/webpack/loaders/html.js
module.exports = {
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
    exclude: /\.async\.(html)$/
}
```